# Eclipse RCP is dependant on its configurations folder, but GIT won't commit all folders/files because they are empty or contain .dll-files

Tags: eclipse, git, dll, eclipse-rcp

I'm currently in the last phase of a project and I have to put the IDE which I used to develop my Eclipse RCP application with into GIT, so that another developer can easily pull everything and start right away.

The problem now is that Eclipse RCP isn't running when there are files missing in its configuration folder. So it is dependant on the content of its configuration folder. Is this normal? The two folders which have to be fully committed are `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi` and `configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime`. Without these folders Eclipse won't start. Is it normal that Eclipse RCP needs those folders to start?

Committing everything by hand with `git add -f file_name` isn't an option I think, because I think the content of the configuration folder often changes.

The problem now is that GIT won't commit all folders because they are empty or only contain dll-files.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi` contains temporary files and varies all the time. I don't think it is a good idea to try and check in / share the Eclipse install at all. Each developer should install Eclipse separately.

Comment: Yes, so it is weird that Eclipse is dependant on `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi`.... I agree with you, but it is a requirement to put the exact IDE under source control. The solution proposed from my boss is to zip everything and commit the zip-file.